# Capitalize first letter following colon and ?: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to capitalize the first letter following a colon or an ? in javascript.

Ex. Coregulation: an integrative analysis --> Coregulation: An integrative analysis

Or: Coregulation? an integrative analysis --> Coregulation? An integrative analysis

I'd like to make the replacement during the body onload, which I already use to make some other replacements. Ex.

> function myscript() {
>
> document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\.\s\,/g,\"\.\,\");
>   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\s\./g,\"\.\");
>   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\.\(/g,\"\. \(\");
>
> }

Does anybody would know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = /([:\?]\s+)(.)/g;

function correctify(full, prefix, letter){
  return prefix + letter.toUpperCase();
}

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, correctify);
```